# Networking disabled after resuming from suspend in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, suspend, mac

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS onto my MacBook Pro Mid-2014, which is now plagued with driver problems. Damn you Apple and restrictive marketing in general.

One of my main annoyances is that, when resuming from suspend (or opening the lid), networking is disabled. When I try to enable it again, nothing happens. No wireless networks are found, nothing.

I'm using the newest drivers for my WiFi card, no problems there. Does anyone have a solution to this?

```
woody@Macbook-Pro:~$ sudo lshw -c network
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 03
   serial: 80:e6:50:24:63:30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.23 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
```

Woody